# Deleting a node from a singly linked list C

Tags: c, linked-list

I am having a hard time figuring out why my delete function is not working. It is a boolean that needs to return if an item was deleted. Any help would be appreciated

```
boolean delete(SLL *list, String str){
    NODE *current, *previous,*temp;
    temp=malloc(sizeof(Employee));
    previous=NULL;
    current = list -> head;


    while(current->next!=NULL) {
        if(strcmp(current->anEmployee->name, str) == 0){
            if(current=list->head){
                list->head=current->next;
            }

            if(previous->next == NULL){//item not found in list
                return 0;
            }
        else { //current is to be deleted
            temp->next=current->next;
            previous->next=temp->next;

            return 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: if(current=list->head){
should be ==?

Comment: also you have a memory leak in the function, the temp variable is not needed

Comment: Hint: Turn on maximum warning levels, and simple things like the = vs. == won't happen anymore.

Comment: Please *ALWAYS* put in typedefs if you use them.
Best case don't use them at all, NODE, SLL gives us no information (apart from using nonstandard capitalization, allcapps are used for macros/constants).
Also you state no information about what does not work (perhaps it's obvious, I did not really read that mess though).

Answer (score 2):

Your if statement where you compare current to the list->head (the root node of the list, initially), is assigning the node to current, rather than comparing it.

Comment: Inside of your loop you advance the root node of the list (i.e.: list->head) rather than the current node, so the string comparison is only ever comparing the list->head's name to the one passed in. It would be worth your time reading Sangeeths links in regard to node removal from a linked-list.

Comment: Also, the previous pointer is set to NULL -- if the string passed in doesn't match list->head's name, it should segfault.

Answer (score 0):

Before writing the code, you need to know the various cases that should be handled in deleting a node in a linked list. The following may help you.

1. [Delete Node from linkedlist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8634327/delete-node-from-linkedlist/8635324#8635324)
2. [Removing all nodes with a certain value in a linked list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8615912/removing-all-nodes-with-a-certain-value-in-a-linked-list/8616233#8616233)