# How to clear memory in c

Tags: c++, c, memory, linked-list, free

I have a struct as follows:

```
struct Node{
int *arr;
int *sol;
struct Node *Next;
};
```

i am creating Node in this way:

```
Node* MyNode = (Node *)malloc(sizeof (struct Node));
MyNode->arr = malloc(sizeof(int)*N);
MyNode->sol=  malloc(sizeof(int)*N);
```

I then add MyNode to a linked list. How can i free memory for an element in the list.
is this correct:

```
pop(){
   free(first->arr);
   free(first->sol);
   first=first->Next; 
}
```

Comment: Which language? Also: there is a `;` missing from your struct definition (*for both languages*).

Comment: What's `Next`? Your `Node` doesn't contain a `Next` pointer.

Comment: In C don't cast the return value of malloc. In C the type `Node` (for the pointer MyNode) doesn't exist. In C use a C compiler for C code :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For any `struct` to be a node in a `linked-list`, you need a `self-referential structure variable` which should be declared as `struct Node *next;`

```
struct Node{
    int *arr;
    int *sol;
    struct Node *next;
}
```

To allocate memory for a node of a linked-list, you need the following:

```
/* allocate memory for a node */
struct Node * MyNode = (struct Node *)malloc((int)sizeof(struct Node));
if (MyNode == NULL) {
    printf("ERROR: unable to allocate memory \n");
    return 1;
}

/* allocate memory for the content of a node */
MyNode->arr = (int *) malloc((int)sizeof(int) * N);
if (MyNode->arr == NULL) {
    printf("ERROR: unable to allocate memory \n");
    return 1;
}

MyNode->sol = (int *) malloc((int)sizeof(int) * N);
if (MyNode->sol == NULL) {
    printf("ERROR: unable to allocate memory \n");
    return 1;
}

/* add the new node to a list by updating the next variable */
MyNode->next = ...
```

If you are not sure about the operations that you need to perform to delete node in a linked-list, you can use a `temp` variable to do the same in an easier way.

```
pop()
{
    struct Node * temp = first;
    first = first->next;
    free(temp->arr);
    free(temp->sol);
    free(temp);
}
```

Thumb rule for `free` - for every `malloc()` there should be a `free()`

OTOH, to go through various scenarios in deleting a node in an linked-list, please refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8615912/removing-all-nodes-with-a-certain-value-in-a-linked-list/8616233#8616233) link.

Answer (score 3):

almost, you need to free the node itself:

```
pop(){
   Node* old_first = first;
   free(first->arr);
   free(first->sol);
   first=first->Next;
   free(old_first); 
}
```

Comment: *nitpick* `old_first` is not declared,there is a compilation error in your answer :)

Answer (score 1):

```
pop(){
   free(first->arr);
   free(first->sol);
   Node* temp = first; //<========
   first=first->Next;
   free (temp);  //<=======
}
```

Comment: @Mat, Roee, give me 20 seconds will you?!

Answer (score 1):

It's close but not correct - you should have as many `free`s as you have `malloc`s. You're forgetting to free the `Node` itself.

To fix it, add a temporary:

```
Node *next = first->next;
free(first->arr);
free(first->sol);
free(first); 
first = next;
```